# Cannot install tidyverse package in R. Error there is no package called

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse

I am attempting to install the package `tidy verse` in R studio and receiving these errors.

```
> install.packages('tidyverse')
also installing the dependency ‘rstudioapi’

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
rstudioapi  0.9.0   0.10             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/tidyverse_1.2.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 88754 bytes (86 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 86 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/kn/b21xc36111z157czpz0swc900000gn/T//RtmpeVGvVh/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘rstudioapi’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rstudioapi_0.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61888 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘assertthat’
Calls: time.to ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rstudioapi’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/kn/b21xc36111z157czpz0swc900000gn/T/RtmpeVGvVh/downloaded_packages’
```

In addition I've attempted to install in base R and receive the same message. I've gone to the temporary folders and unzipped the package and moved that over to the library folder. When I attempt `library(assertthat)` it gives me an error that there is not a valid package installed.

I've successfully installed `tidyverse` before on this machine, but when trying to use it this time it told me it was not installed, so I've attempted to reïnstall it.

Comment: As the error says, the `assertthat` package is not installed, so you would have to install that first.

Comment: I attempted that but got the same error: there is no package called 'assertthat'.

Comment: Try restarting a fresh vanilla session, run `install.packages('assertthet')` then `library(assertthat).  If that goes well then restart and try installing tidyverse.

Comment: @TylerRinker After I deleted my .Rhistory, and .Rdata and .Rprofile files, and attempted to reinstall that seemed to work. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, throw that down as the answer for other future seekers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted my .Rhistory, .Rdata, and .Rprofile files, restarted R and was able to install `tidyverse` with no issues.

Comment: I cant believe it was this simple. I struggled for 30mins but then followed this & bam. Sorted

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my [own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77678526/9434803). It seems R is trying to load a package that is not present, which may be cause by configurations in .Rprofile or .Rprofile.site. Anyway it might not be necessary to delete all the files. I circumvented this by starting R with from terminal with the `--vanilla` flag (E.g. `R --vanilla`), which will prevent loading of any of the user config files , and then running `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my computer and installed devtools using `install.packages("devtools")`.

After that I made sure to **put Rtools on the PATH**, simply following the instructions here: [Using Rtools40 on Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Afterwards, I was able to install tidyverse using `install.packages("tidyverse")`.