# Unable to install package "stringi", Error: there is no package called 'stringi' (in R)

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringi

I've been trying to resolve an issue in VS Code, where the R Language Server is unable to load, and produces the following error message:

```
R Language Server (8931) started
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted

R Language Server (8931) exited with exit code 1
```

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393514/9434803) indicates the issue may lie with the `stringi` package. Long story short, I ended up removing the `stringi` package, and tried reinstalling it, resulting in a similar error message to the one above:

```
$> install.packages("stringi")

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘stringi’
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpu5V2g7/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("stringi") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

I coud use some help understanding the error message and how to resolve the issue.

---

##### Update:

I tried installing a different package:

```
install.packages("fortunes")
```

This returned in a similar error as the one above, `stringi` is missing.

I then tried removing `tidyverse` and `stringr` and then install `tidyverse` again, which returned the error message below:

```
> remove.packages("tidyverse")
> remove.packages("stringr")
> install.packages("tidyverse")

Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Execution halted
```

Comment: Can you install any other package? `install.packags("fortunes")` say?

Comment: remove tidyverse, ie remove.packages('tidyverse'), remove stringi/stringr, restart kernel/rstudio, install tidyverse

Comment: I tried installing `fortunes`, but it rendered the same error as above. I then removed `tidyverse` and `stringr`, and tried reinstalling `tidyverse` again. Now I get the error: `Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Execution halted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55328491/9434803) suggests that the problem lies with R trying to load `stringi` and then `tidyverse` when these weren't installed correctly.

Running R from terminal with the `--vanilla` flag and then installing `tidyverse` resolved the issue:

###### E.g.

```bash
$> sudo R --vanilla
```

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
```